# Cant save the worksheet in vba script

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping thru all .xls documents in a directory and changing one line in each files component "ThisWorkbook"

Everything works fine, the code opens the files and I can see in run time that the line "test" is inserted into ThisWorkbook. But the save does not work. Is the save function only for sheets? How do I save the changes in the Component?

```
  excelfile = Dir(path & "*.xls")
  Do While excelfile <> ""
    If excelfile <> "merni.xlsm" Then
        Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & excelfile)
        wbResults.Unprotect Password:=""
        DoEvents
        Set codeModule = wbResults.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").codeModule
        With codeModule.InsertLines(3, "test")
        End With
        wbResults.Save
        wbResults.Close
    End If
    excelfile = Dir
  Loop
```

Comment: But then is that line being written to the workbook where the code resides? `ThisWorkbook` is different from `ActiveWorkbook` or a specific workbook by name in that `ThisWorkbook` is where your code is called from.

Comment: Yes, its being written to the correct file, but save does not save the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
Sub AddTest()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim cm As CodeModule

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dick\Book3.xls")
    Set cm = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule
    cm.InsertLines 3, "test"
    wb.Save
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

But with this line

```
    With cm.InsertLines(3, "test"): End With
```

It won't event compile.  InsertLines is a method and doesn't return an object so I'm pretty sure you can't use that with a With block.